# How to save an array in mapping and get the value in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, arrays, mapping

I want to create a mapping with an array of values.
For example,  I want to create a mapping of address that will hold the array of tokenIds that address holds.

> **0x0000XXXXX[0] = 989**

> **0x0000XXXXX[1] = 121**

Below is what I am trying in code:

```
struct Token {
    uint token;
}
mapping(address => Token[]) public addressMintedTokens;

function setTokens(_receiver, tokenId) internal {
addressMintedTokens[_receiver].push(tokenId);
}
```

Unfortunately, this is not working and giving an error
***Member "push" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in struct***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert a key-value pair in your mapping, you can either use this syntax:

```
uint tokenId = 1729;
addressMintedTokens[_receiver] = Token({ token: tokenId });
```

Or this syntax:

```
uint tokenId = 1729;
addressMintedTokens[msg.sender].push(Token(tokenId));
```

Comment: This worked for me.

`uint tokenId = 1729;
addressMintedTokens[msg.sender].push(Token(tokenId));`

Comment: @AnkeshSrivastava I have updated my answer to account for the alternative solution